# asp.net get a specific word from textbox

Tags: asp.net, string

I would like to know how to get a word(s) from a textbox when these word(s) starting with a specific symbol.

For example if the text says:
**Hi @new world. This is a @test text**

I want to get the words **new** and **test**

Answer (score 0):

can u try this?

```
List<string> yourTextArr = yourText.Split(new Char [] {' '} ).ToArray().Where(x => x.StartsWith("@"));
List<string> thatsWhatUWantToGet = new List<string>();


foreach (var eachWord in yourTextArr)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(eachWord) && (eachWord.StartsWith("@"))
    {
        eachWord = eachWord.Substring(0, eachWord.Length-1);
        thatsWhatUWantToGet.Add(eachWord);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is some what correct because with this the end result will be **@new** instead of **new**. Kindly modify your solution :)